# Problem with RunProcess

Tags: external-calls, command-line

I'm trying to use the `RunProcess` function to run docker on Mac OS using Mathematica. But there is a problem:

```
RunProcess[{"docker", "run", "hello-world"}]
```

[image]

It works when using Windows 10

Comment: In the past I have noticed that the PATH that WL uses in `RunProcess` is somehow different from the one on your machine. Can you specify the full path to `docker`? Perhaps `/usr/bin/docker`?

Comment: If you want the WL `PATH` to match the Bash path `SetEnvironment["PATH" -> Import["!source ~/.bash_profile; echo $PATH", "Text"]]`. If you are using zsh then you probably want to `source ~/.zshenv`.